# Group a query when teacher, subject are the same and there is no time interval between classes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

Below I will put the structure of some tables to illustrate what I am trying to do.

Considering that the time of each student's class is 30 minutes, I would like to select the student's schedule, but I need to group the records in which the class schedules are sequential (30 minutes each, without interval) and the teacher and subject are the same

I'm using SQL Server 2017.

student

```
id      name
1       Oliver
2       Jack
3       Harry
```

teacher

```
id      name
1       Amelia
2       Olivia
```

subject

```
id       subject
1        Mathematics
2        Science
```

schedule

```
id  startdatetime            idstudent   idteacher    idsubject
1   2019-05-30 08:00         1            1           2
2   2019-05-30 08:40         1            1           2
3   2019-05-30 09:10         1            1           2
3   2019-05-30 09:40         1            2           2
4   2019-05-30 10:10         1            2           1
```

When selecting by idstudent, I would like to display the result in a grouped as follows:

```
Qty    startdatetime       teacher    subject
1      2019-05-30 08:00    Amelia     Science
2      2019-05-30 08:40    Amelia     Science   grouped in a single row(qty 2) because the class time has 30 minutes without interval, teacher and subject are the same.
1      2019-05-30 09:40    Olivia     Science
1      2019-05-30 10:10    Olivia     Mathematics
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you attempted to write this query? If so, add it to your post.

Comment: The timestamp[s are 40 minutes apart but you claim that you want them grouped when they are 30 minutes apart.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff The grouped line is "2019-05-30 08:40" and "2019-05-30 09:10"

Comment: @Ryan Wilson My difficulty is that I do not know how to compare if there is a time interval between classes. I'm starting in SQL Server. I even think I could use something like CTE or stored procedure, but as I'm coming from Firebird I'm having a lot of trouble

Comment: @Marcoscdoni . . . I changed the formatting of the tables so no scrolling is necessary.  When I viewed the data, it only showed four rows in the `schedule` table and four rows in the desired results -- so it didn't look like anything was being aggregated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of group-and-islands problem.  I am focusing only on the `schedule` table.  You can join in other tables as you see fit.

To determine where a group begins, use `lag()`.  Then a cumulative sum defines the group and aggregation gets what you want:

```
select count(*) as qty,
       idstudent, idteacher, idsubject
from (select s.*,
             sum(case when prev_sdt > dateadd(minute, -30, startdatetime)
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) over (partition by s.idstudent, s.idteacher, s.idsubject order by s.startdatetime) as grp
      from (select s.*,
                   lag(s.startdatetime) over (partition by s.idstudent, s.idteacher, s.idsubject order by s.startdatetime) as prev_sdt
            from schedule s
           ) s
     ) s
group by by idstudent, idteacher, idsubject, grp
order by min(startdatetime);
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff! I'll try it

Comment: Answering an obvious homework question with what is basically just a code dump  is not helpful to future readers or the OP. Could really be closed as duplicate as there are plenty of other questions asking effectively the same thing, e.g. this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931719/how-to-group-consecutive-rows-together-in-sql-by-multiple-columns which got almost exactly the same answer!

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff. You helped me a lot. One more question: what would be the best way to change this query to display field "startdatetime" and teacher name?

Comment: @Marcoscdoni . . . Use `min()` for the startdatetime.  Use joins to bring in names from the reference tables.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff after some tests I verified that the query was not grouping correctly, so I edited the answer. I'd be grateful if you could check it out.

If you can help me with one more question: In this query, I would like to display line by line the total amount that a certain student has done previously for that subject of the current row. Could I do this using a conditional criterion? Example: show the total of classes already done for the subject, but only that with presence to the student? Something like count (*) where presence = 1

Thanks again.